# Canvas Animation Kit Experiment... ...how to clear the canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, html, canvas

I can make a obj to use the canvas to draw like this:

```
MyObj.myDiv = new Canvas($("effectDiv"), Setting.width,  Setting.height);
```

Then, I use this to draw a rectangle on the canvas:

```
    var c =  new Rectangle(80, 80,
        {
            fill: [220, 40, 90]
        }
    );
    var move = new Timeline;
    move.addKeyframe(0,
        {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
    );
    c.addTimeline(move);
    MyObj.myDiv.append(c);
```

But after I draw the rectangle, I want clear the canvas, but I don't know which method and how to do this... ...

O...one more thing:
it is the CAKE's web site:
[Link](http://glimr.rubyforge.org/cake/canvas.html#KeyboardTest)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearing the canvas:

```
canvas.clear = true; // makes the canvas clear itself on every frame
canvas.fill = somecolor; // fills the canvas with some color on every frame
// with canvas.clear = false and low-opacity fill, fancy motion blur effect

Removing the rectangle from the canvas:
rectangle.removeSelf();
or
canvas.removeChild(rectangle);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this method:

```
MyObj.myDiv.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Which effectively colours the entire canvas in the background colour.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is:

```
MyObj.myDiv.width = MyObj.myDiv.width;
```

Comment: Note that this does not work perfectly for Safari, despite what [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html#divingin) claims.

Answer (score 0):

I found that resizing the canvas works like magic, even if you're not really changing the size:

```
canvas.width = canvas.width
```

Comment: Note that this does not work perfectly for Safari, despite what [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html#divingin) claims.